# What is the total number of elements in the set $G \times V$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set $G$ represents the toppings Gino's pizza offers for their pizzas.

$$G= \{\mathsf{pepperoni},\,\mathsf{sausage},\,\mathsf{onions},\,\mathsf{peppers}\}$$

The set $V$ represents the toppings Veggies Pizza offers for their pizzas.

$$V=\{\mathsf{peppers},\,\mathsf{onions},\,\mathsf{carrots},\,\mathsf{artichokes},\,\mathsf{zucchini}\}$$

What is the total number of elements in the set $G \times V$?

Comment: Could you give some examples of what elements of $G\times V$ look like?

Comment: How many elements in G?  How many elements in V?

Comment: Hint:  the symbol $\times$ is used for the Cartesian product of sets for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
&\mathbf{Veggies’:}\\
\mathbf{Gino’s:}&
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
&\text{peppers}&\text{onions}&\text{carrots}&\text{artichokes}&\text{zucchini}\\ \hline
\text{pepperoni}&\\
\text{sausage}&\\
\text{onions}&\\
\text{peppers}&
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The analogy one of my professors always used was "shirts and pants".  If you own 5 shirts and 4 pairs of pants, how many outfits do you have?